# Graphql Spring boot subscription client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I am trying to implement a simple subscription client for graphql using Rsocket and spring boot. My Service works fine and I know my subscription mapping works as I am able to retrieve it from the command line using rsc. But when I try to fetch the subscription and use RSocketGraphQlClient, it's unable to map the field from the response. It returns Scala Map.Map1 object which it cannot caste to Entity of My Object(Simple Pojo to map response). All examples I can find work with a return type of String and are very simple, so I cannot find anything more comprehensive. Any help would be appreciated, or if you can point me to a good reference document to write a rsocket subscription client for Graphql? As I understand, I may be not coercing schema on my return object but I cant figure out if thats the case. Below is the relevant code:

```
var rsocketDoc = """
                subscription {
                    getSecuritiesSubscription {
                        secId
                        rowStatusType
                        label
                    }
                }
                """;
var d = rSocketGraphQlClient
            .document(rsocketDoc)
            .executeSubscription()
            .mapNotNull(response -> {
                if (!response.isValid()) {
                    log.info(response.getData());
                    throw new RuntimeException(response.getErrors().toString());
                }
                final SecurityQl data1 = response.field("getSecuritiesSubscription").toEntity(SecurityQl.class);
                    log.info("data " + data1);
                    return data1;
                });
log.info(d.toString());
d.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

stack trace:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path [getSecuritiesSubscription], data: Map(getSecuritiesSubscription -> Map(secId -> 111111, rowStatusType -> null, label -> Blah Blah Blah))
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path [getSecuritiesSubscription], data: Map(getSecuritiesSubscription -> Map(secId -> 111111, rowStatusType -> null, label -> Blah Blah Blah))
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:140) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.graphql.support.AbstractGraphQlResponse$DefaultResponseField.initFieldValue(AbstractGraphQlResponse.java:123) ~[spring-graphql-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.springframework.graphql.support.AbstractGraphQlResponse$DefaultResponseField.<init>(AbstractGraphQlResponse.java:71) ~[spring-graphql-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.springframework.graphql.support.AbstractGraphQlResponse.field(AbstractGraphQlResponse.java:46) ~[spring-graphql-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.springframework.graphql.client.DefaultClientGraphQlResponse.field(DefaultClientGraphQlResponse.java:66) ~[spring-graphql-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at com.tfgam.stream.processor.controller.SecurityController.lambda$getSecuritySub$2(SecurityController.java:141) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$mapNotNull$24(Flux.java:6428) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at io.rsocket.core.ResolvingOperator$DeferredResolution.onNext(ResolvingOperator.java:513) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RequestStreamRequesterFlux.handlePayload(RequestStreamRequesterFlux.java:330) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.ReassemblyUtils.handleNextSupport(ReassemblyUtils.java:94) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RequestStreamRequesterFlux.handleNext(RequestStreamRequesterFlux.java:407) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleFrame(RSocketRequester.java:255) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.RSocketRequester.handleIncomingFrames(RSocketRequester.java:211) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer$InternalDuplexConnection.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:248) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:129) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at io.rsocket.core.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.onNext(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:48) ~[rsocket-core-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:377) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:411) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333) ~[netty-codec-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454) ~[netty-codec-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to map the result to your gql types.

1. Inject a `objectMapper`.
2. convert the `data` value(in the response map) to your gql types.

There is an example from my Spring Graphql Sample project(written in Kotlin).

```kotlin
client.document(subscriptionQuery)
    .executeSubscription()
    .map { response: ClientGraphQlResponse ->
         objectMapper.convertValue(
             response.getData<Map<String, Any>>()!!["commentAdded"],
             Comment::class.java
         )
     }
     .subscribe { comments.add(it) }
```

Check [the complete integration tests in my example project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-graphql-sample/blob/master/spring-graphql-rsocket-kotlin-co/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/IntegrationTests.kt) which uses `RSocketGraphQlClient`.

Comment: This did not work. my object i flux of flux of Scala maps, when i am trying to map it to my GQL schema, its throwing cannot cast scala map.

Comment: Not sure the certain problem in your case, my example is a complete application and working well. From your log, the `data` in response is a Map, it is same as my case. And your `log.info(d.toString());` line is also problematic.

Comment: log.info(d.toString());, was using this just to see whats there and to break points so you can ignore that. THe problem is my subscription is a Flux<Flux<Type>> not Flux<Type> this is because my data resolver returns a flux from upstream. So flux of flux needs to be flatmapped

Comment: I do not think Flux<Flux>is correct  for a subscription.  If you want to log the data in the Mono/Flux,  add a `log()` to it and see the details directly.  log.info( a flux/mono.tostring) is wired,  I do not check the toString impl, it could be a blocking.

Comment: unfortunately, my upstream provides a flux as return type and it gets wrapped in another flux by default by the subscription. Not sure how to faltten it or just return the orginal flux as that does not seem to work

Comment: Flux `concat` and `concatMap` can concat multi fluxs into one flux, but the subscription publisher requires a connectable flux, a generic flux will not work.

Comment: But your case, create a flux based on an existing flux, use a Flux.from is ok.